# How do to set run time options when embedding mono?

Tags: mono

Like these options:

```
Usage is: mono [options] program [program-options]

Development:
    --aot                  Compiles the assembly to native code
    --debug[=]    Enable debugging support, use --help-debug for details
    --profile[=profiler]   Runs in profiling mode with the specified profiler module
    --trace[=EXPR]         Enable tracing, use --help-trace for details
    --help-devel           Shows more options available to developers

Runtime:
    --config FILE          Loads FILE as the Mono config
    --verbose, -v          Increases the verbosity level
    --help, -h             Show usage information
    --version, -V          Show version information
    --runtime=VERSION      Use the VERSION runtime, instead of autodetecting
    --optimize=OPT         Turns on or off a specific optimization
                           Use --list-opt to get a list of optimizations
    --security[=mode]      Turns on the unsupported security manager (off by default)
                           mode is one of cas, core-clr, verifiable or validil
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

--config -> mono_config_parse ()

--trace -> mono_jit_set_trace_options ()

--runtime -> mono_jit_init_version ()

--verbose and --optimize -> mono_set_defaults () and mono_parse_default_optimizations ()

--profiler -> mono_profiler_load ()

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in mono 4.x

```
mono --optimize=float32 program.exe
```

or

```
const char* jit_options[] = {"--optimize=float32"};
mono_jit_parse_options(1, (char**)jit_options);
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue